# I have a python dataframe where i have to add a new column by doing few comparisons as below to see if if any delay or its on time

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

Getting this error while running the program

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 4, in 
> ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

p_df=pd.read_csv("data.csv",dtype=str)
p_df['rundt'] = pd.to_datetime(p_df['rundt'], format='%y%m%d')
p_df['statrt'] = pd.to_datetime(p_df['startt'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
p_df['endt'] = pd.to_datetime(p_df['endt'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
p_df.insert(7, "slatm", p_df['slatm'])
p_df['slatm'] = p_df['slatm'].astype(str)
p_df['slatm'] = p_df['slatm']+" " + "14:00:00"
p_df['slatm'] = pd.to_datetime(p_df['slatm'])

p_df['currentt'] = dt.datetime.now()
p_df['currentt'] = pd.to_datetime(p_df['currentt'])

p_df["slatrck"] = np.where (p_df['EndTime'].isin(['NaT'])) & (p_df.slatm > p_df.currentt), "TBA" ,
np.where ((p_df['EndTime'].isin(['NaT'])) & (p_df.slatm < p_df.slatm)), "BRCH",
np.where ((~p_df['EndTime'].isin(['NaT'])) & (p_df.slatm > p_df.slatm)), "MEET",
np.where ((p_df['EndTime'].isin(['NaT'])) & (p_df.slatm < p_df.currentt)), "BRCH"))))
```